# Keyboard shortcuts for colors in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I've been looking all around the internet but couldn't find an useful answer.

My problem is actually fairly simple: I want to create the shortcut "**CTRL+1**" to change my *front color to Red*, "**CTRL+2**" to change it to *Green*, and "**CTRL+3**" to change it to *Blue*.

I'm a beginner in Photoshop and I don't know if this can be achieved. The thing is that I'll be teaching maths over a full-screen black canvas, and I need a quick, unobstrusive way to pick colors without having to open that ugly color picker.

Any similar solution that can address my problem will be welcome as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Not directly. However what you can do is this: Create a script for each colour that you want a assign to a hotkey (One for red, one for green, one for blue). Create an action (for each colour) that plays back that script (file > scripts > my script) and then bind that action to a hot key.

The script you want is this:

```
function setForegoundColour(r,g,b)
{
    var tempColor = new SolidColor;
    tempColor.rgb.red = r;
    tempColor.rgb.green = g;
    tempColor.rgb.blue = b;

    // set the foreground colour
    foregroundColor = tempColor;
}

setForegoundColour(255,0,0);
```

Change the values in the function setForegoundColour to the colour you want. This will change the foreground color to red.

To get the hotkey to run the script: 
That's easy. Record a new action. (Run the script - file > Scripts > blue_foregroundcolour.jsx and then hit stop! This is important otherwise you continue to record stuff and all hell breaks loose! Then set that action to a hotkey. So in short you press a hotkey, it'll play back the action that runs the script and the foreground colour will change.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. One question: once I create the scripts and actions, how do I bind those actions to a hot key? (Yes, I am that new to Photoshop). Thank you for your time again!

Comment: I've added that as part of the answer.